# Scala Lift - ActorPing alternative

Tags: scala, lift

I've recently implemented the ajax comet upload with progress found here:

https://github.com/mbk/ajaxupload_with_comet

When compiling I get an error saying ActorPing is deperected, what should I be using instead?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [LAPinger](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.actor.LAPinger%24) is what you're looking for.